# How to make Active Record associations work without creating a foreign_key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I want an `item` to be able to get an associated record from `ItemType` table:

```
item = Item.first

item.item_type # <--- ERROR
```

But I get an error:

> SELECT  "item_types".* FROM "item_types" WHERE "item_types"."item_id"
>   = ? LIMIT 1  [[nil, 11]] SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: item_types.item_id: SELECT  "item_types".* FROM "item_types" WHERE
>   "item_types"."item_id" = ? LIMIT 1 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
>   SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: item_types.item_id: SELECT 
>   "item_types".* FROM "item_types" WHERE "item_types"."item_id" = ?
>   LIMIT 1

From error I can see that ActiveModel tries to access `item_id` column.
But I do not want to create an `item_id` column inside my `ItemType` table...  It is an enumeration table with types of items such as:

```
#id|name

1|"Task"
2|"User Story"
3|"Bug"
4|"Feature Request"
```

**Item model**

```
#
# Table name: items
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  name         :string
#  created_at   :datetime         not null
#  updated_at   :datetime         not null
#  item_type_id :integer
#

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :item_type
end
```

**ItemType model**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: item_types
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class ItemType < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only defined the relationship in model `Item` but you have to define it in model `ItemType` too:

```
class ItemType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end
```

Comment: It did not help. I still get this error: SELECT  "item_types".* FROM "item_types" WHERE "item_types"."item_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [[nil, 21]]
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: item_types.item_id: SELECT  "item_types".* FROM "item_types" WHERE "item_types"."item_id" = ? LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: item_types.item_id: SELECT  "item_types".* FROM "item_types" WHERE "item_types"."item_id" = ? LIMIT 1

Comment: What if you change the relation in the `Item` model to: `belongs_to :item_type`?